# Get Names of Sub-Folders - Perforce Java API

Tags: java, file, api, directory, perforce

I am trying to write a method which takes a path in Perforce e.g

```
//depot/...
```

and spits out any sub-directories within it

```
//depot/folderA
//depot/folderB
//depot/folderC
```

I have tried using,

```
 public List<IFileSpec> getIFileSpecList(String file) {
    List<IFileSpec> fileList = null;
    try {
        fileList = iServer.getDepotFiles(
                    FileSpecBuilder.makeFileSpecList(new String[] {file}), false);  //Get list of file(s) in path
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    return fileList;
 }
```

but in my case the depot contains too many files which are allowed be requested in one single query.

So my question is, is it possible to retrieve sub-directories within a directory in Perforce using the [P4](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4java-javadoc/) Java API

**Edit**

I am looking for the Java equivalent of the command `p4 dirs //depot/*`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is the IServer.getDirectories() method: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/server/IServer.html#getDirectories%28java.util.List,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29